# what have I to use uml or ER model

Tags: uml, entity, relationship

I know that UML is a general-purpose modeling language, but is it being used as a data model for describing a database like ER? Or is it being used only as a notation for entity relationship diagrams?

I mean: which data model tool would you use when you have to design a database for a company?
is the ER model still being the best choice?

Answer (score 0):

Both can be regarded as equivalent when modeling database schemas. In fact, most database tools offer now both notations as alternatives when modeling the database.

I offer a more (personal) opinion on the differences between the two [here](http://modeling-languages.com/the-only-thing-i-miss-from-the-er-language/) but from a practical point of view use the one you prefer (and forget about a purist interpretation of their semantic differences)